# Datatable in angularjs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am using angular datatable to display the response from the http request 
I will send the request to web API that will communicate with the SQL Server database and gives the response
It is working fine for the response that are having the data, but for null response the datatable displayed in the UI is displaying the values from the previous response

Can anyone please help me to intimate like "There are no records inserted for the given request" when the response is null ?

```
Angular JS:
    $scope.currentPage = 0; //current page
    $scope.entryLimit = 10;

    $scope.prevPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
            $scope.currentPage--;
        }
    };

    $scope.nextPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage <  ($scope.filteredItems/$scope.entryLimit) - 1) {
            $scope.currentPage++;
        }
    };

    $scope.setPage = function () {
        $scope.currentPage = this.n;
    };

    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };


    $scope.range = function (size,start, cu,elimit) {
        var ret = [];




        if( ($scope.filteredItems/$scope.entryLimit)  < elimit)
        {
            if(($scope.filteredItems/$scope.entryLimit) ==0)
            {
            elimit = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                elimit = Math.ceil($scope.filteredItems/$scope.entryLimit);

            }
        }
        var end = parseInt(cu)+parseInt(elimit);

        console.log(size,start, end);

        if (size < end) {
            end = size;
            start = 0;
        }
        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            ret.push(i);
        }
        console.log(ret);

        return ret;

    };


HTML:
 <div ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
    <div class="col-md-2">PageSize:
        <select ng-model="entryLimit" class="form-control">
            <option>10</option>
            <option>20</option>
            <option>50</option>
            <option>100</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Filter:
        <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()" placeholder="Filter" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h5>Filtered {{ filtered.length }} of {{ totalItems}} total </h5>
    </div>
    </div>
       <div>
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0" >

        <br/>
        <br/>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover " style=" outline: 1px solid orange;"  >

        <thead>
        <tr>

                <th ng-repeat="(key,value) in items[0]"  ng-click="sort_by(key);" >{{key}}</th>
        </tr>


        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="items in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit ">
          <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in items" >  {{value}}  </td>

        </tr>


        </tbody>

    </table>
               </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <h4>No details found</h4>
           </div>
       </div>
    <div class="col-md-12"   ng-show="filteredItems > 0 ">

        <div colspan="6">
            <div class="pagination pull-right">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
                        <a href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a>
                    </li>

                    <li ng-repeat="n in range(filteredItems, currentPage, currentPage , 5) "
                        ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}"
                        ng-click="setPage()">
                        <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
                    </li>

                    <li ng-class="{disabled: (currentPage) == filteredItems - 1}">
                        <a href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

    </div>
```

My Http resonse will be resent in $scope.items.

Thanks

Comment: if possible create a DEMO code. It would enable people to help

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate the response before populating the table...
Something like

```
    if(response!== null){
    $scope.items={};
    return;
    }
    else{
    $scope.items=response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe you are keeping the response from the API call in $scope for longer than needed.

Destroy and refresh the model object in $scope prior to API call so that the $scope only has objects from the new response.

eg.

```
    stories.destory()
```

In your controller, say your model

```
$scope.items.destroy();
// API call to receive results form server,
// now check if you received items response from server, if not display the message to the user.
```

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: The real problem I am facing is if the response is null the data table in UI is having the previous data . I want to display like " no data for this request " instead of the previous one

Comment: Deepa, the reason its showing old data is beacuase that model is sill in scope. I think if you destroy the old model before calling server / api, then validate the response you receive, you should be able to show a notification / message to the user that no results are retrieved.

Comment: Hi Paul ,
I got what you said. :-)

Comment: could you please help me with some sample code to destroy the scope variable before sending each request to API?

Comment: Yes your answer  is  correct. I have cleared the old data by creating one new function .It worked ..:-) thank you :-)

Comment: Would be great if you accept the answer as correct in stackoverflow Thanks!